# Why does a background img in a div require height but not width to display?

Tags: css, html, background-image

CSS

```
.one {
color: blue;
border: 2px solid;
background: blue url("http://img136.imageshack.us/img136/3964/longthinkg5fk.png") repeat ;
height: 1000px;
}
```

Why is the height necessary but width is optional?

Comment: a div by default has its width set to 100% of its parent element. height is not set by default.

Answer (score 0):

Because a `<div>` is a *block-level* element and it takes **100% of its parent's width** by default, but it has **`height: auto`** CSS declaration by default which will be calculated to *`0`* in this case.

> A block-level is an element which has a type of display of *block*
>   (`display: block`).

When you place a `<div>` element directly into `<body>`, the division element takes 100% width of the body (which it has **100% - 2 * 8px** width of the screen itself, by default).

In order to display a division (`<div>` tag) on the screen, you need to put a **content** inside, or set a **specific height**.

Answer (score 0):

This is because a `<div></div>` is by default set to `display:block` which means the elements width is **default to 100% width**; But with no content inside, the `div` has no height